# How can I tell when a project milestone will be released (no date set for milestone)?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth

The spring-cloud-sleuth project's 2.1.3 milestone's issues are all closed on GitHub however there is no release date set.  Is there a way that I can find out the release date?  Is there a mailing list or some other forum?  Or is contacting the maintainer(s) directly the only course of action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is part of a release train, the dates are set in one place.

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/milestones?direction=asc&sort=due_date

Comment: That's great, however there's no date set for the Greenwich.SR3 release though currently

Comment: When we have one, we'll set it